# how to add + symbol on input focus get + on console too

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where I want to add + symbol on the input focus & want to add user data with + sign on console,

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  var phone = document.getElementById('number').value;
  console.log(phone);
});
```

```html
<form id="form" action="/" method="post">
  <div class="tex_field">
    <input type="text" id="number" required/><span></span><label>Phone Number<sup class="Display" id="error_sup_phone">*</sup> <span id="PhoneNumberErrorMessage" class="ErrorMessage"></span></label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="">Register Now</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const form = document.getElementById("form");
  const phoneField = document.getElementById('number');
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    const phone = phoneField.value
    console.log(phone);
  });
  phoneField.addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
    e.target.value = "+"
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form" action="/" method="post">
  <div class="tex_field">
    <input type="text" id="number" required/><span></span>
    <label>Phone Number<sup class="Display" id="error_sup_phone">*</sup> <span id="PhoneNumberErrorMessage" class="ErrorMessage"></span></label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="">Register Now</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to help the user enter the right format by starting them off by adding a `+` automatically, that’s great. But you should communicate the expected format in any case, and also provide some validation.

Additionally, I assume you’d only want to add a plus if the field is empty?

```js
document.querySelector('#number').addEventListener('focus', e => {
  const i = e.currentTarget;
  if (i.value === "") i.value = "+";
});
```

```html
<form id="form" action="/" method="post">
  <div class="tex_field">
    <input type="text" id="number" required placeholder="+12 4567890" /><span></span><label>Phone Number<sup class="Display" id="error_sup_phone">*</sup> (+12 34567890) <span id="PhoneNumberErrorMessage" class="ErrorMessage"></span></label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="">Register Now</button>
</form>
```

Did you consider using [`<input type="tel">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel#pattern_validation)? This would offer optimised on-screen keyboards that allow the user to enter the +.

[image: A screenshot from a browser on an Android phone, showing a website with a telephone input, and an open on-screen keyboard optimised for telephone numbers]

### Separate the country code from the number

The validation of international telephone numbers is difficult, due to different formats. You risk excluding valid numbers by enforcing too much. Even letters are valid parts of phone numbers, used especially in the USA.

Hence, validating whether the user actually put in a country code ore simply added a + is very difficult. So it became a best practice to separate the country code from the number.

Especially since most people do not dial out of their country on a regular basis and don’t even know their country code, combining them into one list is helpful:

```html
<form id="form" action="/" method="post">
  <div class="tex_field">
      <select aria-label="Country Code">
        <option value="+1">+1 USA and Canada</option>
        <option value="+33">+33 France</option>
        <option value="+49">+49 Germany</option>
      </select>
    <input type="text" id="number" required />
    <label>Phone Number<sup class="Display" aria-hidden="true" id="error_sup_phone">*</sup> <span id="PhoneNumberErrorMessage" class="ErrorMessage"></span></label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="">Register Now</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use below code for this.

```
   jQuery("#number").on("focus", function () {
        jQuery(this).val("+");
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).